# RxJs: filter an Observable<Array<IEntity>>

Tags: rxjs

I've an `Observable<Array<ISource>>` where `ISource` is:

```
interface ISource {
   id: string;
   funding: string;
}
```

I need to filter the sources where `funding === "debit"`.

I've tried several approaches but I'm not been able to get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for example like this:

```
let data: ISource[] = [{id:"a", funding: "debit"}, {id:"b", funding: "bla"}, {id:"c", funding: "debit"}];

Observable.of<ISource[]>(data)
  .map(array => array.filter(item => item.funding === "debit"))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Note that the `array.filter` is the `Array.filter` method and not `Observable.filter`.

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/raroyur/5/edit?js,console